# Remove user mention in bot message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, botframework

Is there a posibility to remove the mention of an user in an bot's answer? I developed a telegram bot with the microsoft bot builder framework and only sending the raw message like an echo bot but in group chat there is always this @username metion before every message my bot sends to the group chat. I added my bot via bot father to telegrams bot list.

[image]

Comment: Confirm this problem. You are not alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not a setting the developer can change. Tracking the issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/483

Comment: That's my issue on github :D I will wait for an answer from the microsoft guys, thanks :)